# How to choose gaps between components suitable for current Look and Feel?

Tags: java, swing, layout

When creating Swing GUI's, how can I best choose the horizontal and vertical gaps to be used to separate components? Something like asked here [Windows Layout Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785750/windows-layout-look-and-feel), but platform independent.

Generally I simply used 5 pixels for everything, that looked reasonable with the Windows Classic theme, but looks somewhat odd when running under Windows 8, especially when there are multiple nested container components (e.g. Dialog -> TabbedPane -> ScrollPane).

I have looked at UIDefaults, but there doesn't really seems to be any hints about component spacing there (I was hoping to find at least a few values that could be used as hints, but LayoutManagers seem to generally use hardcoded deafults, e.g. FlowLayout uses a hardcoded 5 pixel spacing).

What approaches can I take to make my layouts more look and feel aware (I am generally using the System Look and Feel) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a layout of components that change a bit to fit your user's platform, then perhaps just use the user's system look and feel with:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Edit to provide solution for specifying more specific gaps.

To specify margin and padding between components you can try using a [box layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html). You might not need to use a box layout throughout the entire Swing code you have either, perhaps have a utility function you use right before you add a component that accepts a Swing component, and a left right top and bottom margin/padding. This function would then return you a JPanel with a box layout with the margin/padding passed, along with containing one component, the one you passed in.

Comment: Ahm, thats exactly what I'm using. The problem is it doesn't magically choose spacing *between* components.

Comment: Oh sorry, well you can try using a [box layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html). You might not need to use a box layout throughout the entire Swing code you have either, perhaps have a utility function you use right before you add a component that accepts a Swing component, and a left right top and bottom margin/padding. This function would then return you a JPanel with a box layout with the margin/padding passed, along with containing one component, the one you passed in.

Comment: I don't get how I would solve my question using BoxLayout. When you write "a left right top and bottom margin/padding", how do you mean to do that? Determining suitable values for those margins is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: `BoxLayout` comes with `Box.addHorizontalStrut` and `Box.addVerticalStrut`, as well as other `Box.` methods for defining space within JComponents.

Comment: Well I can't help you determine suitable values for margins as that's more of a design question, but like Gorb said, BoxLayout has the ability to add the margin/padding. The link I gave shows a variety of ways to add margin/padding.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not *how* to add spacing in a layout, but *how much* spacing to add to conform to current look and feel. It may well be there is no way to solve this generically.

Comment: Well if you find out what some good values are, you can always store all of them and at run time query what the current look and feel is and use the respective values.